# Silverlight datagrid cell edit event

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid, binding

I have a checkbox column bound to a dependency property. When editing the checked property is it possible to update the bound property immediately rather than waiting for the cell to lose focus?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can look [here](http://sweux.com/blogs/smoura/index.php/wpf/2009/05/19/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iii-playing-with-datagridcolumns-and-datagridcells/), there is a solution (go to:  `Creating an AutoCommitCheckBoxColumn`)

### summary:

derive from `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` & handle `checkBox_Checked` & `checkBox_Unchecked` events.

```
public class AutoCommitCheckBoxColumn : DataGridCheckBoxColumn
{
    private void checkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommitCellEdit((FrameworkElement)sender);
    }

    private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommitCellEdit((FrameworkElement)sender);
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(
        DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var checkBox = (CheckBox)base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);

        checkBox.Checked += checkBox_Checked;
        checkBox.Unchecked += checkBox_Unchecked;

        return checkBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events but you'll have to update the bound property yourself.